# Postman: Is there a way to pass a variable with dynamic iteration number to a request?

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

**Snippet:**
**1st Postman Request - Tests Tab:**

```
let iterationCount = pm.info.iteration+1;
console.log(iterationCount);
const response = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set(`location_${iterationCount}`,  response.label);
```

**2nd Postman Request**

```
 "CalibrationMask": 
{
               "Length": {{location_${iterationCount}}},
               "Width": 0,
               "Id": "3fc388275b724e82819cf44603db69c3"
 }
```

When I pass the above variable to 2nd postman request, it doesn't work. What am i missing here? Syntax is incorrect in request? Please suggest

Requirement here is to fetch a value from 1st response for each iteration and store it as environment variable
For eg: Location_1, Location_2 , Location_3 and pass this value to subsequent requests in the same collection

Answer (score 0):

Put both the requests within the pre-request script in a for loop; for the actual request, use a sample get api request.